# What is the difference between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I know there are basic differences like no plugins and such. But if I use Visual Studio Pro at work and want to do some ASP.NET MVC apps at home, would I find Visual Studio Express a hindrance?

Comment: Impossible to tell.  Try it, count the number of "oh crap!"s per hour.

Comment: Actually, Visual Studio 2010 Express allows some extensions. Have a look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7940249/723845

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio Expression is a free but less featureful version of Visual Studio Pro.  As you've noticed it doesn't support plugins and a number of other features.  It does support the editing of MVC web applications so it should be just fine for your purposes.

Here is a very useful FAQ page for Visual Studio Express

- http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/Support-faq.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The Wikipedia article on the package outlines a list limitations for each component.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express

Answer (score 4):

Aside from plugins, there are only a few things behind the scenes that are different, but for the most part you won't notice a huge difference -- unless you want to create plugins for VS or collaborate with a Team through the Team Foundation.  [Here's the MS comparison of versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: There are no licensing restrictions according to the Visual Studio Express FAQ http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/Support-faq.aspx

Comment: Right you are @JaredPar.  Oops.

Comment: I actually thought you were right at first and went searching for the actual license restriction when I found the FAQ.